# How to ignore non-float value

Tags: python

I have a USB temperature logger that uploads to Cosm every 30 seconds. The issue I'm having is that every 5 minutes, when I run the command it reports a text error instead of a number.

So I'm trying to figure out a way to get it to either loop until it receives a number or just ignore the text and resume the script (it quits with an error otherwise).

My very inelegant solution is to do this:

```
  # convert regular error message to number
    if temp_C == "temporarily": # "temporarily" is used as it happens to be the 4th word in the error message
            temp_C = 0.0
```

The current body of code is:

```
while True:
    # read data from temper usb sensor
    sensor_reading=commands.getoutput('pcsensor')

    #extract single temperature reading from the sensor

    data=sensor_reading.split(' ') #Split the string and define temperature
    temp_only=str(data[4]) #knocks out celcius reading from line
    temp=temp_only.rstrip('C') #Removes the character "C" from the string to allow for plotting

    # calibrate temperature reading
    temp_C = temp

    # convert regular error message to number
    if temp_C == "temporarily":
            temp_C = 0.0

    # convert value to float
    temp_C = float(temp_C)

    # check to see if non-float
    check = isinstance(temp_C, float)

    #write out 0.0 as a null value if non-float
    if check == True:
            temp_C = temp_C
    else:
            temp_C = 0.0
```

Comment: What does the error message say ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Python, it is often easier to ask for forgiveness than permission ([EAFP](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp)).  When you encounter a `ValueError`, `continue` to the next iteration:

```
try:
    temp_C = float(temp_C)
except ValueError:
    continue # skips to next iteration
```

Or more compactly (consolidating most of your function):

```
try:
    temp_C = float(sensor_reading.split(' ')[4].rstrip('C'))
except (ValueError, IndexError):
    continue
```

Comment: Will this convert non-float values to "0.0" (it looks like it will). I was hoping to be able to skip over the error instead of reporting 0.0 as I had done previously.

Comment: Ah.  If you want to skip them entirely, put `continue` in your except-clause.  Edited the answer to do this.

Answer (score 4):

Just catch the `ValueError` exception that occurs when the conversion fails:

```
try:
    temp_C = float(temp)
except ValueError:
    temp_C = 0.0
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a lot tidier - however, I was hoping to avoid replacing it with a zero and just skip that run of the code (as I'm graphing these values, dropping to zero all the time looks messy).

Comment: You can skip the value as shown above. Another option is to re-use the previous measurement.